# Losing information when using views in PostGIS/QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a layer defined by a complex chunk of SQL which builds a multiline string from a bunch of single lines.  This works fine.  I now need to join this to a table that has all the meta data for these new lines but I could not figure out how to do the SQL.

I ended up creating a view with the name and the multigeom and performed the join on this.  That works fine in PostGIS but when I try and load them in QGIS I get errors on the views because QGIS can not figure out which was the geometry column.  These I can 'fix' temporarily in the 'load PostGIS layer' dialogue which tells me exactly what is wrong but I have to do this every time I attach to the data base.  The DB Manager just flags the table as bad.

Is there a way to fix this once in the view?  I rather like using the view as it makes it much clearer what is going on with the SQL.

For the record here is the SQL that defines the view:

```
SELECT f.part_of, st_multi(st_collect(f.the_geom)) AS multigeom 
  FROM (SELECT line_master.part_of, line_master.type,
          (st_dump(line_master.the_geom)).geom AS the_geom FROM base.line_master) f 
  WHERE ((f.part_of IS NOT NULL) AND ((f.type)::text = 'track seg'::text)) 
  GROUP BY f.part_of;
```

Alternatively I need to define the layer in one query by joining this to a table of meta data with columns like name, description, etc by matching part_of and name.

Comment: I have managed to work around this by doing the join in the layer definition using the DB Manager.  I.e. instead of creating a view "Tracks" that did the join between the *view* with the geom and the table with meta data I used the DB Manager sql window to do the join and then load the table.  Interestingly when I "create view" it won't let me load the view. Which comes back to the original assertion that information must be getting lost somewhere